# In Poker, what happens with the next players if paying the big blind puts a player all-in?

Tags: poker-texas-holdem, poker

In Texas hold'em poker, if a player doesn't have enough chips to pay the big blind, what happens if the next players want to call? Must they pay the entire big blind or not?

For example, a tournament starts and after some time, the SB/BB is 50/100 but the player who must pay the BB has only 60. Other players want to call only.

- Player A (SB): mandatory bet 50 and is waiting.
- Player B (BB): mandatory bet 60 chips and all-in.
- Player C has more than 110 and wants to call, must they pay 100 or only 60?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Player B is considered all in and Player C must still match the full blind amount and there will just be two possible winning piles depending on who wins. If Player B wins they would win 60 chips per player that paid the big blind and the next high hand would win the rest.

[pokerlistings.com](http://www.pokerlistings.com/odd-poker-rules-and-exceptions)

> When a player's stack is less than the amount of the small blind, they are automatically considered all-in in the next hand they play, regardless of position.
>
> If the player's stack is larger than the small blind but smaller than the big blind, they will be considered all-in in any position other than the small blind, assuming they fold for their option.
>
> When all-in, the player can only win the amount of their stack, plus that same amount from all of the callers and blinds. If the person has less than the big blind, they can only win the portion of the blind equal to that of their stack.

Comment: Regardless of position is not what I am used to and is not what the WIKI link of my answer indicates.

Answer (score -2):

[WIKI poker betting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betting_in_poker#%22All_in%22)

> All-in before the deal
>   If a player does not have sufficient money to
>   cover the ante and blinds due, that player is automatically all-in for
>   the coming hand. Any money the player holds must be applied to the
>   ante first, and if the full ante is covered, the remaining money is
>   applied towards the blind.

After the flop this should not come up.  If you have less than a blind behind you should should bet it pre flop.  Most rooms would enforce minimum call of 1 bb.

Comment: This does not appear to add anything new that was not already answered.

Comment: @JoeW It a more general source - WIKI.   I feel that it adds value.  I don't think what you site as ALL positions are all-in if less then 1 bb is universal.  After the flop is not in the question but that adds compared to your answer.